# Cannot open https://stackoverflow.com/

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow

I have not been able to open the link https://stackoverflow.com/ recently. The page said "You are not allowed to perform this action."

But I can open "https://meta.stackexchange.com/" now.

This is my personal laptop, Windows 11. I tried Firefox and the Google browser, but I got the same error.

1. no block in network settings
2. no setting for the [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)).
3. no DNS setting.
4. location US.

Is there anywhere to check it?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Could you provide the HTTP request status and response headers?

Comment: Thanks for answering! Here is request header for you reference. Cache-Control:
max-age=30
Content-Type:
text/plain
Date:
Sat, 11 Nov 2023 05:43:08 GMT
Request URL:
https://stackoverflow.com/
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
451 Unavailable For Legal Reasons
Remote Address:
172.64.155.249:443
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Sec-Ch-Ua:
"Google Chrome";v="119", "Chromium";v="119", "Not?A_Brand";v="24"
"Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest:
document
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)

Comment: Looks like you are in China, or at least browsing the internet with ISP from China, hence being blocked by the notorious [Great Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall) (which is already well known to block Stack Overflow). Using proxy to USA address doesn't always work, probably.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Yes, I am in China but  using US company VPN, I can open it before. Checked the status code:451, looks you are right. thanks sharing!

Comment: China is strong and smart enough to block VPN as well, so sadly what matters most is your actual location, and it's a dead end. If you want to use SO, you'll have to simply be in different place.